# Complex line integral independent of path

Tags: complex-analysis

Could you please verify my solution?

> Let $f$ be holomorphic on an open set $U$ which is the interior of a disc or a rectangle. Let $p,q \in U$. Let $\gamma _j : [a,b] \to U, j = 1,2,$ be $C^1$ curves such that $\gamma _j(a) = p, \gamma _j(b)=q, j =1,2$. Show that $$\oint _{\gamma _1} \ fdz = \oint _{\gamma _2} \ fdz$$ *Function Theory...* 2.2

Solution: consider $\gamma := \gamma_1 - \gamma_2$. This is clearly closed by definition (and is piecewise $C^1$), so $$\oint_{\gamma} \ fdz = 0 = \oint_{\gamma_1}\ fdz - \oint_{\gamma_2}\ fdz$$

as desired.

Is this sufficient?
I got the idea from (what seemed to be) a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/71480/7850). Having just downloaded my first text on Diffential Forms, I can't fully grasp what is said there, but I took a stab at a similar argument.

This exercise appears to be saying that the line integral is independent of path. There is mention of the complex case on [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Complex_line_integral), but their approach was to convert the integral to something real valued. I would also be *interested* in a solution that uses that technique.

Thanks

Comment: I can't help but wonder whether the interesting formation "ingested" was produced by a spell-checker gone astray or by association with a widespread pronunciation of "interested" with an affricate that sounds not too unlike "ingested" (but with the emphasis on a different syllable)?

Comment: Yes, @joriki, this was typed using iOS! Do you have any thoughts on the rest? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably mention that since the domain is simply connected, Cauchy's theorem says that $\int_\gamma f \ dz = 0$.

Comment: That would justify my use of that equality, then. Thanks